# Quickcheck, defining Arbitrary instances using a function whose result depends on its arguments

Tags: haskell, testing, generator, quickcheck

I have a function `arbExample` to generate a random `Example` data type which depends on a numbers of functions.

I am trying to do some property testing by doing `quickCheck prop_example`, the problem is I don't know how to define an `Arbitrary` instance for `Example` which uses `arbExample`.

I like to be able run `quickCheck prop_example` while specifying the `Gens` data structure which `arbExample` uses.

```
data Example = Example
    { myInt  :: Int 
    , myList :: [String]
    } deriving (Show)

data Gens =  Gens
    { gen1 :: Gen Int
    , gen2 :: Gen String }

arbExample :: Gens -> Gen Example
arbExample gens = do 
    i  <- gen1 gens 
    xs <- vectorOf i (gen2 gens)
    return Example{myInt=i, myList=xs}

prop_example :: Example -> Property
prop_example example =  do
    let len = length (myList example) 
    monadicIO $ do 
        -- result of running some program
        successful <- run $ (\e -> return False) example  
        case successful of
            True  -> return ()
            False -> fail "failure "

instance Arbitrary Example where
    arbitrary =  arbExample _ {- ??? -}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `forAll` combinator which has the signature:

```
forAll :: (Show a, Testable prop) => Gen a -> (a -> prop) -> Property
```

A quick example:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

genA :: Gen Int
genA = choose (-100,100)

genB :: Gen Int
genB = choose (1,100)

prop_example :: Int -> Bool
prop_example n = n > 0

testA = quickCheck $ forAll genA prop_example
testB = quickCheck $ forAll genB prop_example
```

`testA` will fail but `testB` will succeed.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Clear, simple, and to the point.