# How can I constraint QuickCheck parameters, e.g. only use non-negative ints?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm new to Haskell. It's very nice so far, but I'm running into copy-pasting for my QuickCheck properties, and I'd like to fix that.

Here's a made-up example:

```
prop_Myfunc :: [Int] -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
prop_Myfunc ints (i,j) = ints !! i == ints !! j
```

This won't work because QuickCheck generates negative numbers, so I get

```
*** Failed! (after 2 tests and 2 shrinks):                               
Exception:
  Prelude.(!!): negative index
```

I've tried to google for solutions to this, and I've found e.g. [NonNegative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:NonNegative) and ==>, but I don't understand how they work.

How can I restrict the above example so that i and j are never negative? And also, so that neither is too high? That is: `0 <= i,j < length ints`

Comment: I think you mean `0 <= i,j < length ints`

Comment: @user5402 Yes, thank you! I'll change that. Will check your answer as soon as I can, it looks very good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constraining wrappers (from `Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers`, if they aren't reexported implicitly) can be used in this way:

```
prop_Myfunc :: [Int] -> (NonNegative Int, NonNegative Int) -> Bool
prop_Myfunc ints (NonNegative i, NonNegative j) = ints !! i == ints !! j
```

You can treat `SomeWrapper a` as `a` with modified distribution. For example, `NonNegative a` ensures that `a >= 0`. After the wrapper was generated, the value can be get with pattern-matching or explicit accessor (`getNonNegative` in this case).

As for constraining the top margin of your indices, I think it's not possible with wrappers (it's impossible in the Haskkell type system to parameterise a type with the value, the list length in this case). However, with the `==>` operator you can add an arbitrary boolean constraint for your test:

```
prop_Myfunc ints (NonNegative i, NonNegative j) = i < l && j < l ==> ints !! i == ints !! j where
    l = length ints
```

It works in other way: when the condition isn't true, it simply discards the current test case. But be careful: if there are too many thrown cases (the condition is too restrictive), the test becomes much less useful. A „lossless“ behaviour can be often achieved with `shrink`ing test data, but it's a whole other topic.

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

First, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074021/866915) for an example of how to write a custom `Gen ...` function and how to use the `forAll` combinator.

And here is how to write a generator for a non-empty list and two valid non-negative indices into the list:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

genArgs :: Gen ( [Int], Int, Int )
genArgs = do
  x <- arbitrary
  xs <- arbitrary
  let n = length xs
  i <- choose (0,n)
  j <- choose (0,n)
  return ( (x:xs), i, j) -- return a non-empty list

test = quickCheck $ forAll genArgs $ \(xs,i,j) -> prop_myfunc xs (i,j)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I learnt a lot from this. Yuuri's answer was more in line with what I wanted, but I wish I could accept. Have an upvote, at least.

Comment: In fact, I like this solution more than my own :)

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation as you and I finally found how to use `==>` here: http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html, in the "Conditional Properties" section.

With your example, you'd have to replace `Bool` with `Property` and insert the requirements about your variables before the property test, as follows:

```
prop_Myfunc :: [Int] -> (Int,Int) -> Property
prop_Myfunc ints (i,j) = (i >= 0 && j >= 0) ==> ints !! i == ints !! j
```

(I haven't tested on this particular example, but it worked for me on a similar case.)

Note the type of `==>`: `(==>) :: Testable prop => Bool -> prop -> Property`.